# How to change the owner of a .co.uk whose owner has died?

Tags: whois

Years ago, I registered a .co.uk domain for my mother using my own 123-reg account. I set the registrant name to hers as it was a gift for her and she would be the owner.

Time passed and she has since died. The domain is still managed by my own 123-reg account and I've set the email address and phone numbers to mine so it still has valid contact details, but I can't change the registrant's name.

I found [this page on 123's support site](https://www.123-reg.co.uk/support/answers/Domains-Archive/Domain-Administration/how-do-i-change-the-listed-ownerregistrant-for-a-co-uk-org-uk-me-uk-domain-name-1266/). Do I perhaps need to ask the executors of her estate to go through the steps of creating a Nominet account as this page describes? What do I need to do to transfer ownership of this domain?

Comment: I did not follow your link, however, in the U.S., you would *have to* get the executor and the estate's legal counsel (there is always a lawyer up your butt even when you die [humor]) to take action on your behalf. That would be enough. From there, any registrar would *have to* satisfy any reasonable request of the estate. I assume that the U.K. would be similar. Cheers!!

Comment: If you don't want to follow some legal procedure, I will suggest to migrate your domain name to another registrar. I personally change my name when I transfer my domain name to namecheap.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, a change of registrant requires the positive acknowledgement of the current registrant (and/or the administrative contact, for example in gTLDs), for obvious reason.

However each rule need exceptions and your case is clearly among them. The specific procedure to follow will depend on the TLD of the domain. You will probably have more luck by contacting the registry directly.

If you look at https://www.nominet.uk/domains/manage-your-domain/ you will find a section "Transferring your domain to someone else" that says the registry could itself handle a registrant change if needed, so you surely need to ask them.
See also next section "Updating your contact details".

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it, if you have access to the registar's account where the domain is held, you can simply login and unlock the domain for transfer, and then pick which registar and account you want to send it to. In other words, if you can login to your mother's registar account you can probably just send the domain to yourself in an account with your name on it.

Answer (score 0):

Nominet domains are different for changing a Registrant, so you can't do it from the Registrars page.

It can only be changed through Nominet, and there is usually a fee for making that change.  I do think you are on the right path though.  Have, "whoever" is in control of the estate try to initiate the Change or Registrant through Nominet.